# How can I target single object value in Angular Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage

In my Angular application I have `maan` field in my database. I am displaying the value of this field twice on my front end. One is static while other value will change.

I am using Angular Local Storage to save the dynamic value in `saveChanges` function.
I am using new variable to store the value

```
var change_single_object = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('LikeWhen') || '{}') as LikeWhen
change_single_object.maan= maan; -------> Here I am trying to access dynamic value (#term reference in html)
```

But the above statement always refer to Static Value. How can I resolve this issue?

Interface

```
export interface LikeWhen {
    maan: string;  
}
```

component.ts

```
export class RufusComponent { 
  @ViewChild('term') editElem!: ElementRef<HTMLTableDataCellElement>;
  
saveChanges(rec: LikeWhen, new_value: HTMLTableDataCellElement) {
 localStorage.setItem('LikeWhen', JSON.stringify(rec));
 var change_single_object = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('LikeWhen') || '{}') as LikeWhen
 change_single_object.maan= maan;-------------> PROBLEM (Refers to static value)

 localStorage.setItem('LikeWhen', JSON.stringify(change_single_object));
}
}
```

.html

```
// --------static value
 <mat-list-item>Static Value Amazon</mat-list-item>
            <mat-list>{{latestData.maan}}</mat-list>
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>

// -------dynamic value
            <mat-list-item>Dynamic Value</mat-list-item>
            <mat-list class="textFields">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td [innerHTML]='latestData.replaceHTML' #term></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>                
            </mat-list>

//button
<button mat-raised-button type='button' [disabled]='confirmDisabled' (click)='saveChanges(latestData, term)'>Confirm
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `setItem` and `getItem` like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');

const cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');
```

For more on this you can look at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

> To Update data dynamically on some event or something , you can use
> angular services and `rxjs` subject like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocalStorageService {
  localStorage: Storage;

  changes$ = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    this.localStorage   = window.localStorage;
  }

  get(key: string): any {
    if (this.isLocalStorageSupported) {
      return JSON.parse(this.localStorage.getItem(key));
    }

    return null;
  }

  set(key: string, value: any): boolean {
    if (this.isLocalStorageSupported) {
      this.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
      this.changes$.next({
        type: 'set',
        key,
        value
      });
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  remove(key: string): boolean {
    if (this.isLocalStorageSupported) {
      this.localStorage.removeItem(key);
      this.changes$.next({
        type: 'remove',
        key
      });
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  get isLocalStorageSupported(): boolean {
    return !!this.localStorage
  }
}
```

this link will help more on this: https://firstclassjs.com/persist-data-using-local-storage-and-angular/

Comment: Yes I am using that, problem is I have `maan` field in my database. I am using this field twice in my front end. I am trying to access 2nd reference `Dynamic value` in front end code. When I try to access it always refers to 1st `Static value` reference. How can I get 2nd reference?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz ,

Comment: Its bit difficult as there is lot of project dependencies, ill try

Answer (score 0):

When you use `JSON.parse()`, it creates a new JSON object from text (meaning its not the same reference to the original data).

In order for this to work in Angular, you would need to pass the original referenced data to the dynamic display/component.

Comment: Okay, can you suggest what I can use? Thanks

Comment: It depends on how and when you are receiving the dynamic data.  Are you receiving changes to the data as the user works on the page, or is it changing from another component? @TejasMehta

In most cases, the easiest way to communicate between components is to use an Angular service based approach.
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4